# Converting int to decimal inside linq statement

Tags: linq

I need to get the decimal result of divide tow integers inside linq statement as in the example:

```
from error in errorslist
select new
{
    res = error.count1 / error.count2
}
```

it return result as integer and I cant use `Convert.ToDecimal` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integer division results in an `int` where the  fractional part is truncated since it can't be stored in the result type(`int`). Therefore at least one of both must be a floating point type.

```
from error in errorslist
select new
{
    res = error.count1 / (double) error.count2
}
```

or

```
from error in errorslist
select new
{
    res = error.count1 / (1.0 * error.count2)
}
```

**Update** If you want the result type to be `decimal` (because of the title of your question):

```
from error in errorslist
select new
{
    res = error.count1 / (decimal) error.count2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn at least one of the values to a `decimal`:

```
from error in errorslist
select new
{
    res = error.count1 / (error.count2 + 0m)
}
```